# Is it possible to capture the close event of popup in this case

Tags: jquery

On click of a Button ,i am showing a popup .

The popup is getting closed if clicked anywhere , my question **is it possible to capture the close event of popup** in this case

Please see this fiddle and click on Position to Window Button

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/65/

My code

```
 <div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
            <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
       <a href="#transitionExample" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">Position to window</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExample" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
                <div class="popup_inner popup_sm">
                    <div class="popup_content popup_myactivelabels_content">
                        <p>Sorry! Now we are not able to delivery these timings</p>
                        <h3>Our Available timings</h3>
                        <p>11am to 2pm</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

$(document).on('click', '.close', function(event) {
$('#transitionExample').popup('open')    
});
```

Please let me know if this possible , thanks in advance .

Comment: what do you want to do with it when you capture the close event?

Comment: Do you want to override close event or you want provide some close button to close this popup?

Comment: @MokshShah , i want to override the close event .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, when the popup shows up there is an overlay which covers rest of the elements except the modal. It has id similar to `transitionExample-screen` . So when you click on this element, the dialog is closed. What you need is to bind the click event on this element. That would be close.

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function (event) {
    $('#transitionExample').popup('open');
});

$(document).on('click', '#transitionExample-screen', function () {
    alert("closing");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/66/

Instead of id, you can use class if you have multiple popups. For class, just inspect the overlay

Comment: @Kiran You can mark it as an answer if this is what you needed.